# Controling link with select option bar, html "effect of back page"

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="shakeme">
    <a id="link" href="javascript: void(0)" >
        <img border="0"  src="basic.png" width="400" height="230" role="button">
    </a>
</div>
```

This is my division with a link inside. As you can see link is void, in other words does nothing.

```
<select onchange="enableLink()" id="first-disabled"  class="selectpicker">
    <optgroup>
        <option selected="selected" value="1000" > Select </option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label=" A ">
        <option  value="1001"> Car   </option>
        <option  value="1002"> Banana  </option>    
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

This is my select option bar, with customizations. I deleted some of its settings not to make the code more confusing. However it is basicly a option select bar.

```
function enableLink() { 
    var e = document.getElementById("first-disabled").value;            
    if( e == 1001 ){
        document.getElementById("link").href="1001.html"; 
    };

    if( e == 1002 ){
        document.getElementById("link").href="1002.html"; 
    };
}
```

With the change it calls the enableLink and sets href to a certain value. Everything works fine for this point. When I change the value in option select bar, after clicking the link it goes to link I want. But when I click "Go Back" button which is in every web browser, it takes the previous info in the page and shows previously selected value. Ex it shows: banana in the select bar.

After that when I click to the link it doesnt do anything, I guess because it also sets the href as empty (void) when I go back to the previous page. How can I make it still go to banana link?

Edit: I thought this problem could be solved with the default select box settings. In other words when I go back why it doesnt make the "select" option as default setting?

Comment: You need to persist the link's state somewhere before you redirect the user. In a cookie, localStorage, hash or something. Then when they navigate back to the page, set the href accordingly

Comment: I guess it is a way, But can I do it with a practical way?

Answer (score 0):

You  have the select's value, not the option's value.
To catch the option value do this :

```
var a = document.getElementById("first-disabled");
var e = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;  

if( e == 1001 ){
    document.getElementById("link").href="1001.html"; 
};

if( e == 1002 ){
    document.getElementById("link").href="1002.html"; 
};
```

Comment: I guess this code wont work because when I click "Go Back" the option select bar wont call the enableLink function, so it wouldnt change anything.